# How to display decoded JSON data?

Tags: php, json

Here's my current code:

```
<?php
$jsonData = file_get_contents('http://example.com/bin/serp.php?engine=google&phrase=stackoverflow');

$phpArray = json_decode($jsonData);
print_r($phpArray);
?>
```

Right now it is showing this on my page:

```
Array ( [0] => stdClass Object ( [idx] => 0 [title] => Stack Overflow [description] => A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers. [url] => http://stackoverflow.com/ ) [1] => stdClass Object ( [idx] => 1 [title] => Stack Overflow - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia [description] => Stack Overflow website logo.png · Stack Overflow.png. Screenshot of Stack Overflow as of December 2011. Web address · stackoverflow.com. Commercial? Yes. [url] => http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow ) [2] => stdClass Object ( [idx] => 2 [title] => Why I no longer contribute to StackOverflow â€” Michael T. Richter [description] => I was active in the StackOverflow (and the broader Stack Exchange) community for a while. I no longer am. Here's why. [url] => http://michael.richter.name/blogs/why-i-no-longer-contribute-to-stackoverflow ) [3] => stdClass Object ( [idx] => 3 [title] => StackOverflow Rank and Percentile - Stack Exchange Data Explorer [description] => StackOverflow Rank and Percentile WITH Rankings AS ( SELECT Id, Ranking = ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY Reputation DESC) FROM Users ) ,Counts ... [url] => http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/6772/stackoverflow-rank-and-percentile ) [4] => stdClass Object ( [idx] => 4 [title] => Newest 'stackoverflow' Questions - Meta Stack Exchange [description] => Download data for StackOverflow User Survey? The DropBox link to download the data for this survey is expired. Is there another place to get the data? [url] => http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/stackoverflow ) [5] => stdClass Object ( [idx] => 5 [title] => Return to StackOverflow.org [description] => StackOverflow.org began as the merging of two ideas that have been kicking around in my head for years. First, I wanted a dorky programming-related domain  ... [url] => http://stackoverflow.org/ ) [6] => stdClass Object ( [idx] => 6 [title] => StackOverflow Update: 560M Pageviews a Month, 25 Servers, and ... [description] => The network of sites that make up StackExchange, which includes StackOverflow, is now ranked 54th for traffic in the world; they have 110 sites ... [url] => http://highscalability.com/blog/2014/7/21/stackoverflow-update-560m-pageviews-a-month-25-servers-and-i.html ) )
```

This is what I'm trying to have display on the PHP page (this is just the first few lines, but I want to actually use all the json data):

```
1.  <a href="http://stackoverflow.com/">Stack Overflow</a>
A language-independent collaboratively edited question and answer site for programmers.

2.  <a href="http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Overflow">Stack Overflow - Wikipedia, the free encyclopedia</a>
Stack Overflow website logo.png &middot; Stack Overflow.png. Screenshot of Stack Overflow as of December 2011. Web address &middot; stackoverflow.com. Commercial? Yes.
```

This part that I don't seem to be understanding is how to take the JSON data and have it formatted like I want.  All the data is there though, so if anyone could show me what I need to change in my current code to get this working, it would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just print the parts of the array you want instead of doing print_r on the whole thing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

when you decode a json string, you'll obtain an array.
if you specifiy TRUE as second parameter, the array's going to be associative.

now, you just have to place the content of your array where you'd like, for example:

```
// here we've the decoded json data
$a = array(
            "link1",
            "desc1",
            "link2",
            "desc2"
     );

// for each data, we make an ordered list with data you need
// in your case you'll have the link and the description on every point
echo "  <ol>
            <li>{$a[0]}</li>
            <li>{$a[1]}</li>
        </ol>

        <ol>
            <li>{$a[2]}</li>
            <li>{$a[3]}</li>
        </ol>   ";
```

tell me if i wasn't clear, i'll edit my answer.